# how to call multi function in single ng-init directice using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just try to call two function in single ng-init of angularjs.but it through error to me.
**My code:**

```
ng-init="function1();function2();"
```

I don't know how to call those function correctly.anyone can give me some ideas to do it.
Thanls advance..

Answer (score 6):

You can create one main function like "init" and call other functions inside that function.

```
ng-init="init()"
```

from your controller

```
function init() {
  function1();
  function2();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the below link, and have a look at the console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/60Ry6hwiunAF12PZclNW?p=preview

HTML

```
<div ng-init='one(); two();'></div>
```

JS

```
$scope.one = function(){
  console.log('one')
};

$scope.two = function(){
  console.log('two')
};
```

Hope this is what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this should work, and probably the reason it doesn't is because you don't have these functions in the scope. Do you have an `ng-controller` on this or ancestor element?

If you do, make sure that these functions are defined on the scope:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.function1 = function(){...};
  $scope.function2 = function(){...};
});
```

Second, you should not be using `ng-init` to call functions at all.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
</div>
```

Instead, call these functions in the controller:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  function1(); 
  function2();

  function function1(){...};
  function function2(){...};
});
```

From [Angular documentation on `ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.